# After disabling offline mode I still get "Disable offline mode and rerun the build" error

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am working on a Kotlin project and when running the project I get this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDevDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:devDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve sale.clear.behavior:sdk-behavior:3.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No cached version of sale.clear.behavior:sdk-behavior:3.0.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of sale.clear.behavior:sdk-behavior:3.0.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of sale.clear.behavior:sdk-behavior:3.0.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of sale.clear.behavior:sdk-behavior:3.0.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of sale.clear.behavior:sdk-behavior:3.0.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of sale.clear.behavior:sdk-behavior:3.0.1 available for offline mode.

Possible solution:
 - Disable offline mode and rerun the build
```

According to their instruction I disabled offline mode

[image]

but after rerunning the project, I am still getting this error. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance

Edited: build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven {
            url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/vstscs/Produtos-Agile/_packaging/BehaviorAnalytics.SDK.Android/maven/v1'
            name 'BehaviorAnalytics.SDK.Android'
            credentials {
                username "psbtrs"
                password "g3lbwrwklmnopqvpr3sdfabasdfasdfll7xsik3a"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the private maven repository to your list of repositories within build.gradle?

Comment: Yes, I have added it along with credentials

Comment: Can you show us how you have added it using placeholder values for your credentials

Comment: Please check the edited question, thank you for taking time and helping

Comment: @MirStephen Have you found the solution for the issue?